# What is the function of the hole at the rear of the airplane?

Tags: aircraft-design, apu

What is the function of the hole at the rear of a plane?
I searched online but didn't get a satisfying answer.

Comment: there are several hole in a typical airplane. you'll get better answers if you provide a picture.

Answer (score 2):

[image: APU]

This one? It's the APU(auxiliary power unit)'s exhaust.

An auxiliary power unit (APU) is a device on a vehicle that provides energy for functions other than propulsion.

> The primary purpose of an aircraft APU is to provide power to start
>   the main engines. Turbine engines must be accelerated to a high
>   rotational speed to provide sufficient air compression for
>   self-sustaining operation. Smaller jet engines are usually started by
>   an electric motor, while larger engines are usually started by an air
>   turbine motor. Before the engines are to be turned, the APU is
>   started, generally by a battery or hydraulic accumulator. Once the APU
>   is running, it provides power (electric, pneumatic, or hydraulic,
>   depending on the design) to start the aircraft's main engines.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxiliary_power_unit